# How to download tar file in react native, then extract and store it, and read files from it later?

Tags: react-native, zip

I have react native app where tar file download is downloaded from url, store it on the device and read files from it after that.
I used rn-fetch-blob and react-native-zip-archive, and I was able to download zip file and extract it. However with tar file it never works with me.
Any solution or another github library suggestions?

```
import { zip, unzip, unzipAssets, subscribe } from 'react-native-zip-archive'
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'
.....
.....
 onDownloadedtionPress() {
   RNFetchBlob.config({
    fileCache: true,
    path: DocumentDirectoryPath + '/my.tar',
   })
    .fetch('GET', 'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/zip_5MB.zip')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        const targetPath = DocumentDirectoryPath
        unzip(res.path(), targetPath)
            .then(path => {
                console.log(`unzip completed at ${path}`)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
            })
    })
}
```